# Bind9 Configuration Zone not loaded due to error

Tags: debian, dns, bind

I am trying to set up my own Bind9 Server, but when starting the Server, I get the following errors:

```
Nov 23 09:52:53 name named[26661]: reverse/172.18.6.234:1: no current owner name

Nov 23 09:52:53 name named[26661]: zone 6.18.172.in-addr.arpa/IN: loading from master file reverse/172.18.6.234 failed: no owner

Nov 23 09:52:53 name named[26661]: zone 6.18.172.in-addr.arpa/IN: not loaded due to errors.

Nov 23 09:52:53 name named[26661]: dns_rdata_fromtext: lehrwerkstatt.lan.db:23: near '172.18.6.234.2': bad dotted quad

Nov 23 09:52:53 name named[26661]: zone lehrwerkstatt.lan/IN: loading from master file lehrwerkstatt.lan.db failed: bad dotted quad

Nov 23 09:52:53 name named[26661]: zone lehrwerkstatt.lan/IN: not loaded due to errors.
```

My configurations:

- `db.lehrwerkstatt.lan` (I removed the real gateway IP)

  ```
  $TTL 3D
  @       IN      SOA     ns.lehrwerkstatt.lan. chantra.lehrwerkstatt.lan. (
                          2022112301       ; serial, todays date + todays serial #
                          8H              ; refresh, seconds
                          2H              ; retry, seconds
                          4W              ; expire, seconds
                          1D )            ; minimum, seconds
  ;
                  NS      ns              ; Inet Address of name server
                  MX      10 mail         ; Primary Mail Exchanger
                  MX      20 mail2        ; Secondary Mail Exchanger
  ;
  ns              A       172.18.6.234
  www             CNAME   www.lehrwerkstatt.lan.
  ftp             CNAME   ns
  gw              A       172.18.6.234
                  TXT     "Network gateway"
  mail            A       172.18.6.234.2
  mail2           CNAME   otherbox
  otherbox         A      172.18.6.234.3
                  TXT     "Otherbox"
  ```
- `172.18.6.234`

  ```
   $TTL 3D
  @       IN      SOA     ns.lehrwerkstatt.lan. chantra.lehrwerkstatt.lan (
                          2022112301 ; Serial, todays date + todays serial
                          8H      ; Refresh
                          2H      ; Retry
                          4W      ; Expire
                          1D)     ; Minimum TTL
                  NS      ns.lehrwerkstatt.lan

  1               PTR     gw.lehrwerkstatt.lan.
  2               PTR     mail.lehrwerkstatt.lan.
  3               PTR     otherbox.lehrwerkstatt.lan.
  5               PTR     ns.lehrwerkstatt.lan.
  ```
- `named.conf.local`

  ```
  zone "lehrwerkstatt.lan" {
        type master;
        file "lehrwerkstatt.lan.db";
        notify no;
  };
  zone "6.18.172.in-addr.arpa" {
       type master;
       notify no;
       file "reverse/172.18.6.234";
  };
  ```

I tried fixing it myself, but it changed nothing.

Comment: `172.18.6.234.2` is not an IPv4 address and hence can't appear in an `A` record. Among other problems...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `reverse/172.18.6.234` you have a leading space  in the first line -  `$TTL 3D`, you need to remove all leading spaces. When you have leading spaces it means to refer to the previous entry.

In `db.lehrwerkstatt.lan`, you clearly do not have correct IP addresses for `mail` & `other`. There should be 4 numbers separated by dots, you have 5.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed that. All errors are fixed now, but I still get a NXDOMAIN when I try to use nslookup no matter if reverse or not

Comment: The zone descriptions should always terminate with a dot to signafy the root. ie `zone "lehrwerkstatt.lan." {`, `zone "6.18.172.in-addr.arpa" {`,  `@       IN      SOA     ns.lehrwerkstatt.lan. chantra.lehrwerkstatt.lan. (` etc... If it is still not functiuoning as expected, then refer to the logs, and you would be advised to study the manual to get the best out of them.

Comment: @Alex_X1 "All errors are fixed now, but I still get a NXDOMAIN when I try to use nslookup no matter if reverse or not –" You need to show exactly which commands you use and exactly which reply to get. Please update your question with further details instead of adding comments.